# RTK query selector returns undefiend while data exist in state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rtk-query

I am tryin to make a get request to my back end with the following way :
The url is http://localhost:5000/shops/id/appointments in order to get the appointments of the specified shop.

on the front end

I am using the useGetQuery by passing an id to it

```
 const AppointmentsList = ()=>{
   

    const {id} = useParams();
    const {
        data:appointments,
        isLoading,
        isSuccess,
        isError,
        error
    } = useGetAppointmentsQuery(id);
```

This hits the back end where I get the id from the path I find in mongo db the document that has that id I pick the data I need from the document and then I json them back with the response.
The response from the back end is exactly this :

```
[{
    active: true,
    customerName: 'Takis Makis',
    service: 'Kourema',
    date: '12/12/2022',
    _id: new ObjectId("63923aac73a0d02225738e69") },{active: true,
    customerName: 'Mixalis Mixaliotis',
    service: 'Lousimo',
    date: '01/-1/2023',
    _id: new ObjectId("63923ac973a0d02225738e6d")},{ active: true,
    customerName: 'Ilias Tontoktoris',
    service: 'Xirisma',
    date: '10/1/2023',
    _id: new ObjectId("63923ae173a0d02225738e72")}]
```

In the front end I recieve the json. My appointmentsSlice is this :

```
import { createSelector,createEntityAdapter } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";
const appointmentsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
 
});

const initialState = appointmentsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const appointmentsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({ 
    endpoints:builder=>({
        getAppointments:builder.query({
            query:(id)=>`/shops/${id}/appointments`,                                       
            validateStatus:(response,result)=>{                       
                return response.status === 200 && !result.isError
            },
            keepUnusedDataFor:60,
            transformResponse:responseData=>{                                                               
                const loadedAppointments = responseData.map(appointment =>{          
                    appointment.id = appointment._id
                    return appointment
                });
                return appointmentsAdapter.setAll(initialState,loadedAppointments)  
            },
            providesTags:(result,error,arg)=>{                        
                if(result?.ids)
                {                                                      
                    return [
                        {
                            type:'Appointment', id:'LIST'
                        },
                        ...result.ids.map(id=>({type:'Appointment',id}))
                    ]
                }
                else return [{type:'Appointment',id:'LIST'}]
            }
        }),
```

Where the api slice is this :

```
import {createApi,fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    //fetchBaseQuery similar to axios
    baseQuery:fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl:'http://localhost:5000'}),
    tagTypes:['Shop','User','Appointment'],
    endpoints:builder =>({})
});
```

And my store is like this

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {apiSlice} from './api/apiSlice';
import {setupListeners} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query';
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        [apiSlice.reducerPath]:apiSlice.reducer,
    },
    middleware:getDefaultMiddleware=>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
    devTools:true
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

And my frontend Routes are :

```
<Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Layout/>}>
        <Route index element={<Public/>}/>
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path='/shops/:id/appointment'></Route> {/*public route to set an appointment */}

     
        <Route path='dash' element={<DashLayout/>}>
          <Route index element={<Welcome/>}/>
          <Route path='shops'>
            <Route index element={<ShopsList/>}/> {/* an admin will be able to see all shop but a shopkeeper will be able to see only his shops*/}
            <Route path=':id'element={<AppointmentsList/>}/>
          </Route> 
        </Route>
       
      </Route>
    </Routes>
```

When I hit the /dash/shops/id out I render a component AppointmentsList. This calls the query useGetAppointmentsQuery(id); On the same component I map over the response to take the ids of the appointments and while I map over them I render for each of them another component named Appointment. This component recieves the id as a prop and uses useSelector select AppointmentsById and return undefiened for each and everyone.

```
const Appointment = ({appId})=>{
    const appointment = useSelector(state=>selectAppointmentsById(state,appId));
    console.log("test:",appointment)

    const navigate= useNavigate();
 
  

    if(appointment){
        const customerName = appointment.customerName;
        const service = appointment.service;
        const date = appointment.date;
      
        const handleEdit =()=>navigate(`/dash/appointments/edit/${appointment._id}`);
        
            return(
                <tr>
                    <td>{customerName}</td>
                    <td>{service}</td>
                    <td>{date}</td>
                    <td><button onClick={handleEdit}>Επεξεργασία</button></td>
                </tr>
            )
    }
    else
    return null
}

export default Appointment;
```

Its driving me crazy.In rtk tools it appears that the query is successfull and the data exist in the state but the selectors are unable to retieve them. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong ? I would be much obliged!

[image: screen shop from redux DevTools]

```
const appointmentsAdapter = createEntityAdapter({
 
});

const initialState = appointmentsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const appointmentsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({ //we use the api slice to inject the endpoints in the original api slice
    endpoints:builder=>({
        getAppointments:builder.query({
            query:(id)=>`/shops/${id}/appointments`,                                        //the query that goes to the /appointments endpoint
            validateStatus:(response,result)=>{                        //making sure there is not an error and we have a status 200
                return response.status === 200 && !result.isError
            },
            keepUnusedDataFor:60,
            transformResponse:responseData=>{  
                                                                             
                const loadedAppointments = responseData.map(appointment =>{          //we map over the Data and we set the note.id to note._id (mongo id)
                    appointment.id = appointment._id
                    return appointment
                });
                return appointmentsAdapter.setAll(initialState,loadedAppointments)   //return the loadedNotes with the new Id property
            },
            providesTags:(result,error,arg)=>{                         //check if there is an id on the result
                if(result?.ids)
                {                                                      
                    return [
                        {
                            type:'Appointment', id:'LIST'
                        },
                        ...result.ids.map(id=>({type:'Appointment',id}))
                    ]
                }
                else return [{type:'Appointment',id:'LIST'}]
            }
        }),
export const {
    useGetAppointmentsQuery,
 

} = appointmentsApiSlice

//returns the query result object
//we use the appointmentsApislice refering to the endpoints and calling getusers endpoint chaining select() 
//this gets the query result
export const selectAppointmentsResult = appointmentsApiSlice.endpoints.getAppointments.select();

//creates memoized selector
//we use createSelector, we pass the selectAppointmentsResult
//a functions comes in and grabs the data from the selectAppointmentsResult
//its not exported
const selectAppointmentsData = createSelector(
    selectAppointmentsResult,
    appointmentsResult=>appointmentsResult.data // normalized state object with ids & entities
)

//getSelectors creates these selectors and we rename them with aliases to use on the appointments
//using destructuring
export const {
    selectAll:selectAllAppointments,
    selectById:selectAppointmentsById,
    selectIds:selectAppointmentsIds,
    //pass in the selector that returns the appointments slice of state
} = appointmentsAdapter.getSelectors(state=>selectAppointmentsData(state)??initialState)
//we use getSelectors,we pass the state , the selectUsersData (??nul colesky operator) and if null then goes to initial state
```

Comment: What is `selectAppointmentsById`? You are not sharing that code, but it seems at the center of everything.

Comment: I am sorry you are right. I edited my question adding the appointmentsApiSlice on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

That `selectAppointmentsResult` method you have there is created by `.select()`, which is equivalent to `.select(undefined)` - and that will always return the cache entry to `useGetAppointmentsQuery()` (== `useGetAppointmentsQuery(undefined)`.

But you call `useGetAppointmentsQuery(id)` - so you would have to create a selector with `.select(id)`. In most cases, this is highly impractical. Generally, you should probably not create a selector for use with `useAppSelector`, but you should be using the `useGetAppointmentsQuery(id)` hook in all components that need that kind of state - and if you really just want to subscribe to a part of the return value, use the `selectFromResult` option.

Comment: thanks. I will try it tomorrow morning with a clear mind and I will come back with results!